# Is the solution set of Ax ≥ B convex set in different situation

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, operations-research

$\Omega_1:\{x\in R^n|Ax=b,x\ge0 \}$
$\Omega_2:\{x\in R^n|Ax\ge b\}$,$A$ is full row rank matrix.
$\Omega_3:\{x\in R^n|Ax\ge b\}$,$A$ is full column rank matrix.
Provided $\Omega_1,\Omega_2,\Omega_3 $ are **not** empty,then which set is to (must) have extreme point?
I consider that I could prove it by proving  the set to be convex set, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Simply follow the definition of set convexity, what is stopping you ?

Comment: For Omega1 I know it's convex, but what's the difference between 2 and 3?

Comment: $A$ is a rectangular matrix, say $m\times n$. In the second case,  $A$ is of rank $m\leqslant n$, and in the third case, $A$ is of rank $n\leqslant m$.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad English. What I really don't understand is the relationship between rank and whether it is convex. What I want to know is the reason why Omega2 has extreme point or has no extreme point.

Comment: Then the title of your question is misleading. Extreme points are (almost) always considered on convex sets. All your sets are convex sets, which can be proven directly by the definition of set convexity. The fact that $A$ has a different rank does not matter in the case of convexity. However, it might have an influence on the existence of extreme points in the set.